# geocode 2 or more locations at same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am trying to get locations from multiple address strings.

I've used below code for single string.

```
NSString *addressStr = @"Neeru'sEmporio,RoadNumber36,Venkatagiri,Hyderabad,AndhraPradesh,India";  //String after removing spaces

    [[CLGeocoder new] geocodeAddressString:orgin completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {
         if(!error)
         {
             CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
             NSLog(@"%f",placemark.location.coordinate.latitude);
             NSLog(@"%f",placemark.location.coordinate.longitude);
             NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[placemark description]]);
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"There was a forward geocoding error\n%@",[error localizedDescription]);
         }
     }
     ];
```

How to get two or more locations from multiple address strings at a time. i.e., want individual lat long for every individual string and after getting all locations I need to run some other code.

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what exactly you want, single lat long using your requested string i.e Neeru'sEmporio,RoadNumber36,Venkatagiri,Hyderabad,AndhraPradesh,India  or you want individual lat long for every individual string

Comment: Hi Katty, I want individual lat long for every individual string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&key=%@

pass address as `esc_add` and create an google api key using [The Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)

One more thing replace all spaces " " with "+"

example https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Neeru's+Emporio,Road+Number+36,Venkatagiri,Hyderabad,Andhra+Pradesh,India&key=YOUR_API_KEY

It will work fine

Comment: just updated my comment with example. Its works for me. Tested on browser. And don't forget to create you api key

Comment: @Satish A did it worked for you or you are looking out for apple geocode ?

Answer (score 0):

There are limits for using apple`s geocoder (eg. batch requesting). For more info see [apple dev forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20499) (apple stuff answers). You can use another services like google (there are limits too) or use own solution built on open street maps (you can use eg. xapi or overpass api).